# Opening DB connection with function, run logic with separate function and then close connection

Tags: excel, database-connection, ado, vba

I want to try and keep my program logic separate from where I open and close the connection to my database

I want to open a DB connection in excel to an Access database in a function that I can re-use to open a connection every time I need it. Then I want to run what ever logic I need to run once the connection is open (single example included).

My code does all of that so far, but after running my logic, I want to close the connection. My problem is knowing how to close the connection properly.

I have the following so far that works: OPEN CONNECTION AND RETURN RECORD

```
Private Function returnRecordSetFromDB(qry As String) As ADODB.recordSet
    Dim rst As New ADODB.recordSet
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=C:\SomeFolder\SomeDB.accdb;"

    conn.Open (strcon)
    rst.Open qry, conn, adOpenStatic
    Set returnRecordSetFromDB = rst
    'I should close "rst" here, but then I can not use the data in my logic function anymore
End Function
```

Function that does the logic that I need to do with the record data:

```
Private Sub populateTrucks()
    Dim qry As String
    Dim returnedRecordSet As ADODB.recordSet

    qry = "SELECT [Trucks] FROM tbl_trucks ORDER BY [Trucks];"
    Set returnedRecordSet = returnRecordSetFromDB(qry)
    returnedRecordSet.MoveFirst
    With Me.cmb_trucks
        .Clear
        Do
            .AddItem returnedRecordSet![Trucks]
            returnedRecordSet.MoveNext
        Loop Until returnedRecordSet.EOF
    End With

    Me.cmb_trucks.ListIndex = 0
    returnedRecordSet.Close
    Set returnedRecordSet = Nothing
End Sub
```

According to me, `rst` in my openDB function is still open since I could not close it, otherwise I can not use my record data, but how do I close it now? I can not close it in my logic function cause the `rst` scope is gone. Do I call a third function that opens the connection again, and closes it? Will it be the same connection or just an instance of a different connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did the following that works fine:

In my DB module:
Declared a global variable -

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
```

Then my open sub -

```
Public Function openDB()
    strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=C:\Users\MRProgrammeringPC\Dropbox\Programming\Meatrite Programme\MRPractise.accdb;"
    conn.Open (strcon)
End Function
```

My logic function(s)

```
Public Function returnRecordSetFromDB(qry As String) As ADODB.Recordset
    rst.Open qry, conn, adOpenStatic
    Set returnRecordSetFromDB = rst
End Function
```

My close sub

```
Public Sub closeDB()
    conn.Close
End Sub
```

Now in any module I just call the open procedure , then the logic procedure than I want to execute, and then the close procedure again.